# Cleaning up orphaned relationships

Tags: relationships

I have a few relationship rows that is causing some errors in the EE install. Turns out these relationships have either the parent id or the child id referencing a entry that no longer exists.

Is it safe to just delete these rows in the relationship table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be safe. Make a database backup first just in case. And for best results test on a local development copy of the site rather than in production.

Comment: thanks. I tried on dev already, and everything seems okay. however, not sure whether EE is doing something else with the table that I'm unaware of. always a bit scarely to delete rows by hand in the DB.